# Make gif button only play when hovering. HTTPS only

Tags: html, button, https, web, gif

I am brand new to this site and I came here because I need some professional help!

I am working on a website (simple editor) and I want to make some of my buttons on the site into gifs that play when hovering and resets when not hovering.

I've got only one option to implement the code ant that is HTML. Specifically HTTPS only as it says in the code box.

I've tried using this code below but it doesn't work. Please help me out guys!

Also. Is there a way to make the button actually clickable in a code snippet like this or am I screwed?

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/O2X6soK.png" onmouseenter="this.src ="http://i.imgur.com/80Q4rzw.gif;" onmouseout="this.src ='http://i.imgur.com/O2X6soK.png';" alt="something pithy">
```

Comment: Well you can start by adding HTTPS to those images so they load over HTTPS instead of HTTP. If your site is using HTTPS, those images won't load over HTTP.

Comment: onmouseenter has 2 double quotes on the left but only 1 double quote on the right.

Comment: to make the button clickable, wrap it with <a href="http://google.com"><img></a>

Comment: Oh I didn't see you guys's comments till now. I am still a real noob at this and I honestly don't know how the <a href="google.com"><img></a>; works. I'd really appreciate a short tutorial of some sort if possible :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/O2X6soK.png" onmouseenter="this.src =`http://i.imgur.com/80Q4rzw.gif`;" onmouseout="this.src ='http://i.imgur.com/O2X6soK.png';" alt="something pithy">
```

You have typo error, use back ticks `img url here`.

To make image button,put image tag inside button. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FaNpG/171/)

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much! I am a huge noob at coding still and I try to learn. Last question I have is if there is a way to make this a button somehow?

Comment: I have updated answer, mark this as answer if it helps.

Comment: Yeah that works great! The issue with the site I work on is that it's  difficult to make the button connect to annother part of the page. Is there a way to attach a link to a specific part of the same page? I have anchors in the editor that I have named but I'm uisure how to make the code jump to them. Thank you for the amazing help btw!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. If you want to add link,you should use `<a>` tag. Wrap your images inside <a> tag. You can make an anchor tag to behave like as a button by adding normal css to it. http://jsfiddle.net/FaNpG/173/

Comment: What I want to do is to make the button move me to a specific part of the same page. For example. I have a home page that I have the button on and I want the button to redirect me lower down on the same page. The issue is that the site inly supports HTTPS and I can't use any CSS, only plain and simple html all in the same place :(